# Chrome not rendering @font-face ttf/woff smooth

Tags: css, icons, font-face, smoothing

I am using the IconMoon @font-face icon font for a project I'm working on.

The font is nice and smoothly rendered when only including the .svg and/or .eot font, or when browsing with other browsers such as IE9. But when browsing the site with Chrome, and including the .ttf and/or .woff format, the icons become very choppy and no anti-aliasing at all. Is there a way to tell Chrome to load the .eot or .svg instead of .ttf or .woff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this css property solves your problem:

```
yourSelector {
  font-smooth: always;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: by the way, the only browser that supports "eot" format is IE. chrome supports "svg" format too and you can include the link to "svg" file in your @font-face style rule, but if "ttf" or "otf" link is also provided, most browsers will prefer to use them.

Answer (score 2):

> I found this works for that issue. I don't think the font-smooth solution actually works.
>
> ```
> @font-face {
>    font-family: 'Montserrat';
>    font-style: normal;
>    font-weight: 400;
>    src: url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
>    src: url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'), 
>        url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
>        url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.svg#montserratregular') format('svg'),
>        url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'); 
> }
> ```
>
> Firefox will pick the last one in the list (woff), working or not, IE will use eot, and
>   Chrome will pick the first one that works (svg). Woff works too in chrome, but causes
>   aliased glyphs, so putting svg ahead of woff solves that.*

This solution works, but causes an extra request in Safari, you could leave your svg below woff like you did originally and add:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansLightItalic';
    src: url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.svg#montserratregular')  format('svg');
  }
}
```

Read about it here: http://hollisterdesign.wordpress.com/2014/04/29/note-to-self-always-use-this-fix/

Comment: SVG fonts either don't work or are deprecated in Chrome (depending on OS). http://blog.chromium.org/2014/08/chrome-38-beta-new-primitives-for-next.html

Answer (score 0):

Put the svg font's url before all others, Chrome will load the SVG and you will get a nice rendering, especially for light font.

Comment: SVG fonts either don't work or are deprecated in Chrome (depending on OS). http://blog.chromium.org/2014/08/chrome-38-beta-new-primitives-for-next.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this little rotation for your font, hope it'll help you.

Example:

```
p{
  transform: rotate(-0.0000000001deg);
}
```

Comment: lol. that kinda works. sadly, the smallest degree that worked was 0.1 deg. which made the page look wonky.